# Automatically translate a site

Tags: html, translation, google-translate

I have a site and have the need to automatically translate it in many supported language (english,spanish,french) to my user.

User (a few selected people) access the site through a link i provide, so is not an issue distribute an ad-hoc link.

I have tried to use Google Translate and all work fine, unless some piece of the site use javascript and received encoded resources from third party.

So for example think i have a static site that i can't translate by translating files on web server (i need to translate them on the fly).
We can say the site the is the following :

```
<html>
    <script>
       function show()
       {
             // Will produce a messagebox with say "test"
             eval(String.fromCharCode(97,108,101,114,116,40,39,116,101,115,116,39,41,59));
       }
    </script>
    <button onclick="show()">
      Show me
    </button>
 </html>
```

If i try to google translate it the 'Show me' label correctly translate but message box does not (in my scenario there are no messages box but the concept is the same, a third party send me encoded data on some event, and display it).

Is there a way to automatically translate such kind of page in my scenario?

Comment: Using `eval()` for use in translations seems pretty dangerous. Your example code evals `alert('test');` which could also send the user's cookies and browser history to somewhere else. The translation would have to know what in the code is parameters and what is text displayed to the user. That is unneccessary hard to do and basically an unsolved problem.

Comment: @PeterKrebs i was asked to integrate my question with more detail, so i have mocked my actual page with something that bheave in the same way but is completley differente. In the production site there are some event based or timer based call to third party service, that will return encoded data (with also text). If a generic solution is found for this mocked example then it will also work for the real page

Comment: Okay sure. Text from 3rd party services is difficult to handle multi-language.. do they have to add the text? Can that not come from your end? Do you have a concrete 3rd party service in mind? Add them as a tag, maybe someone has done it already.

Comment: @PeterKrebs no unfortunately i work in an old propietary ecosystem based on IBM AS400 products, so services that i call are custom solutions (not stanrd nor multi-language). My best bet so far is to translate the whole page after few second from the page ready, with such euristics i hope the page has fully loaded all the data

Comment: Ah ok. So if that legacy code assumes you use `eval()` to put anything in the website that is almost made to be non-translatable. Seems your only option is to hide the content, quickly translate behind the scenes and show the elements of the page. Hope SEO is none of your worries.